# How to create an async function that runs parallely with telethon's event handler?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I know there's an answer out there. I have been searching for some time couldn't find it. Please look at the code below.

```
import logging
import asyncio
import time
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

from telethon import TelegramClient, events


api_id = '**'
api_hash = '**'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def check_message_exists(event):
  time.sleep(5)
  print(event, time.time())

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = [-100**]))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    asyncio.ensure_future(check_message_exists('Got message'))    



client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I want `my_event_handler()` to run without waiting for the `check_message_exists()` to end. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

replacing `time.sleep(5)` with `await asyncio.sleep(5)` solved the issue. See below for the full code.

```
import logging
import asyncio
import time
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

from telethon import TelegramClient, events


api_id = '**'
api_hash = '**'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def check_message_exists(event):
  await asyncio.sleep(5)
  print(event, time.time())

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = [-100**]))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    asyncio.ensure_future(check_message_exists('Got message'))     



client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```